# Problems with printing the array.Assembly Language

Tags: arrays, assembly, output, x86-16

I've got some problems with printing array on the screen.
User firstly have to enter elements(numbers) of array from the keyboard, but when i'm trying to print it i've got problems-- it prints different symbols(letters) ,as many as many numbers were entered by the user and then it loops.
MASS-- is our array
SUM- is some message,don't mind it/

```
OUT_ARRAY PROC NEAR;==============================OUT 

 OUT_AR:
 MOV AH,02H
 MOV DL,MASS[SI]
 ADD DL,30H
 INT 21H
 INC SI

LOOP OUT_AR

 XOR SI,SI
 MOV AH,9
 LEA DX,SUM
 INT 21H
 XOR DX,DX
 XOR BX,BX

CYCLE:
 XOR AX,AX
 ADD DL,MASS[SI]
 INC SI
 INC BX
 CMP SI,5

LOOP CYCLE 

RET

OUT_ARRAY ENDP
```

p.s.
-i'm using emu 8086.
-If you already have some sample procedures ,which prints arrays,i'd like to have a look on them. and i'll be grateful to you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 OUT_AR:
 MOV AH,02H
 MOV DL,MASS[SI]     ; Where is SI initialized? You should clear si before you enter the loop
 ADD DL,30H
 INT 21H
 INC SI

LOOP OUT_AR          ; CX is set the by the caller? If not it is also not initialized
```

The question you need to ask here is: Which values are actually printed? You are looping through the array and adding 0x30 to each value.

What does this mean? Obviously you know that the ASCII code for a '0'-'9' is 0x30 - 0x39 so you try to print each digit individually. But what values are stored in `MASS`?

If you have only values there between 0-9 then your algorithm works. Assuming that you have arbitrary values in that array in the range 0-255 then if the value is i.e. 0x60 and you add 0x30 to it, you are printing an accented 'E' (depending on your locales setting).

So what you need to do is, you must convert the number in the array to a decimal string, and only then can you print it properly.